# how to consolidate results of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wondering how to go about consolidating an array.  The $all array, shown below, is an example of data in an array that is actually being returned from a database query.  The goal is to put the data into a single dimension array using integers as the keys in the final array.

```
$all = array(0=>array('ItemID' => 12), 1=>array('ItemID' => 13), 2=>array('ItemID' => 14));
echo "<pre>" . print_r($all, 1) . "</pre>";

/*
goal for format of consolidated array:
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 14
)
*/
```

Comment: Note that your `0 =>... 1=>...` are completely redundant. Just write `$all = array(array('ItemID' => 12), array('ItemID' => 13), array('ItemID' => 14));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a bit lazy aren't you?

```
$data = array();
foreach($all as $k=>$v)
    $data[] = $v['ItemID']:
```

Answer (score 0):

This little snippet returns your wished array:

```
$all = array_map(function($val) { return current($val); }, $all);
```